# How to autofill formula in excel, when a cell is deleted

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to find a way to automatically add serial numbers when a data is entered in a row. Is there a way to auto fill formula across a column?

I have used this formula, =IF(B1<>"",A1+1,""), =IF(B2<>"",A2+1,""),...  this works fine but the problem is when i delete contents in a row. the pattern breaks. I have tried COUNTA function as well, it works fine as well. But here also the problem is when I delete contents in a row, the formula gets deleted from the cell. Is there a way to retain formula and just delete the data without using "Go To" dialog OR Is there a way to auto fill formula in an entire column?

Comment: Use something like INDEX(A:A,row()) and Index(a:a,row()-1)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A))
```